# Suppressing the Replace All alert in BBEdit

Tags: bbedit

When using BBEdit to do a Find and Replace All, the application triggers an alert popup box/window with the results of the replacement (e.g. '6 occurrence(s) of "foo" were replaced with "bar".') This alert blocks the application until it's dismissed. This has always annoyed me.

How can the confirmation alert for a BBEdit Replace All be suppressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I found the answer on [this page](http://groups.google.com/group/bbedit/browse_thread/thread/7fc81d10801ccfad). I don't see it anywhere on Stack Overflow so I'm dropping it here.*

Quit BBEdit if it's running, then issue the following from the command line terminal:

```
defaults write com.barebones.bbedit ReportReplaceAllResults -bool NO
```

Fire up BBEdit and enjoy not having to close the box each time you do a Replace All.